# how to get post order by post id wp_query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, order, array, sort

I have 4 posts and I displaying 2 posts per page.

```
$ids = array('16085','16088','16083','16091');

$options = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'paged'     => $paged,
        'meta_query' => $meta_query,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'post__in ' => $ids,
        'orderby' => 'post__in',
);
$get_properties = new WP_Query( $options );
```

I want to display posts in a specific order is given $ids array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so you want to define posts order by yourself. WP_Query allows you to do that - you'll have to use `orderby` => `post__in` to achieve it. And that's what you do.

So why isn't it working? Because of a typo ;)

Ordering posts by `post__in` preserves post ID order given in the 'post__in' array. But you don't pass `post__in` param in your query (you pass `post__in` - additional space at the end).

```
$ids = array('16085','16088','16083','16091');

$options = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged'     => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'post__in ' => $ids, // <-- here is the additional space
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
);
$get_properties = new WP_Query( $options );
```

So this should work just fine:

```
$ids = array('16085','16088','16083','16091');

$options = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'post__in' => $ids, // <-- there is no space anymore in here
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
);
$get_properties = new WP_Query( $options );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
$get_properties = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page','posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,'paged' => $paged,'meta_query' => $meta_query,'tax_query' => $tax_query, 'post__in' => array( 32, 30, 27, 45) ,'orderby' => 'post__in' )  );


echo "<pre>";print_r($get_properties);exit;
```